# Pushing a dynamic configuration file using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to push the configuration files to all the app_server

Here is my inventory file

```
[app_servers]
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
```

and my configuration file looks below

```
conf 
{
name : configuration file
ip   : a.b.c.d
}
```

My task is to push this configuration file and the IP value should be replaced with the Ip for that server.

for example , in 1.2.3.4 configuration file will be

```
conf 
{
name : configuration file
ip   : 1.2.3.4
}
```

and in 5.6.7.8 , it will be

```
conf 
{
name : configuration file
ip   : 5.6.7.8
}
```

I tried using the replace command and iterate using group as below, but for each server its looping twice due to which not getting correct IP replaced.

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - replace: dest=/home/ubuntu/config regexp='a\.b\.c\.d' replace=' {{ hostvars[item]['inventory_hostname'] }}'
      with_items: groups['app_servers']
```

Is there any easy to approach this and have things simple but dynamic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a one-line change to an existing file on the remote host, you can use `lineinfile`.

However, you say that the config file should be pushed to the remote host, in which case it is better to use the `template` module, writing the file in a Jinja2 template, and populate it with variables before pushing it.

Get the remote host's IP from the [facts gathered by Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts), for example from `ansible_default_ipv4`.

Locally you have `config.j2`:

```
{
  name: configuration file
  ip: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
}
```

Task that builds file from template:

```
- name: upload config file
  template:
    dest: /home/ubuntu/config
    src: config.j2
```

For example, the resulting file `/home/ubuntu/config` on a remote host with IP 192.168.10.10 would be:

```
{
    name: configuration file
      ip: 192.168.10.10
}
```